# Sorting a text document python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the text document: The first string is the type of metal, the second is the amount of the metal bars, the third is the weight, and the fourth is the value.

```
Gold 1 5 750

Silver 1 1 400

Rhodium 1 4 500

Platinum 1 6 1000
```

I have to sort this list by value using insertion sort. Here's what I have so far

```
def sortMetalsByValuePerBar(metals):
    for i in range(1,len(metals)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and metals[j-1] > metals[j]:
            metals[j - 1], metals[j] = metals[j], metals[j - 1]
            j -= 1
    return metals
```

Is this correct?

Comment: remember to thumbs up the answer if it was usefull to you..

Answer (score 1):

Try to learn from this solution.

```
data="""
Gold 1 5 750
Silver 1 1 400
Rhodium 1 4 500
Platinum 1 6 1000
"""

data = filter(None, data.splitlines())
data = [l.split() for l in data]
data = [ (l[0], int(l[1]), int(l[2]), int(l[3])) for l in data ]

def insertion_sort(l, keyfunc=lambda i:i):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        j = i-1
        key = l[i]
        while keyfunc(l[j]) > keyfunc(key) and (j >= 0):
            l[j+1] = l[j]
            j -= 1
        l[j+1] = key

insertion_sort(data, keyfunc=lambda l: l[3])

for l in data:
    print(l)

# Output:
# ('Silver', 1, 1, 400)
# ('Rhodium', 1, 4, 500)
# ('Gold', 1, 5, 750)
# ('Platinum', 1, 6, 1000)
```